Am I safe if I disconnect the scam website that I connect before?
Am I safe if I disconnect the scam website that I connect before?
And if I delete the old wallet and create a new wallet is that be secured my trust wallet?

Disconnecting an account from a website does literally nothing. Just stop visiting the scam website.
You need to change the wallet if you shared the private key or if you approved some tokens or signed some messages. If you don't remember what you did while visiting the website, changing the wallet is the safest approach. Just remember to transfer your coins to a new one :)
